# Device does not send any content after sending MDM Command

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I have successfully managed to send a MDM push notification to the device and the device responds with an Idle status. However, when I sent an MDM Command:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">
<plist version=\"1.0\">
  <dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>4FB2550B-ADFD-425C-BF6C-92CEDE747F23</string>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
      <key>RequestType</key>
      <string>InstalledApplicationList</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The device does not contain any response. It closes connection somehow. I am writing the XML and then reading the stream to check for a response over the same connection. when i close the connection and then resend a push notification, I get back this empty response:

```
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.18.130.31:1234
User-Agent: MDM/1.0
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-apple-aspen-mdm
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

I also tried deviceinformation but to no avail:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>7C28313A-BFE7-4430-A516-BB16C8F6F750</string>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
      <key>RequestType</key>
      <string>DeviceInformation</string>
      <array>
        <string>DeviceName</string>
        <string>OSVersion</string>
        <string>BuildVersion</string>
        <string>ModelName</string>
        <string>Model</string>
        <string>ProductName</string>
        <string>SerialNumber</string>
        <string>DeviceCapacity</string>
        <string>AvailableDeviceCapacity</string>
        <string>BatteryLevel</string>
        <string>CellularTechnology</string>
        <string>IMEI</string>
        <string>MEID</string>
        <string>ModemFirmwareVersion</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

It is supposed to send an Acknowledged state or at least an error. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: What happens when you send a `DeviceInformation` command? Do you get the device's information?

Comment: no nothing. just always the same response with content length 0

Comment: <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200 -> but the command did not take place

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I had an encoding of 16 and not 8 in the XML plist I was sending.

Answer (score 0):

I had this symptom too, although my problem was different.

You should not sign your XML.